# Using variables inside a for loop, instead of numbers

Tags: file, text, for-loop, file-io, int

I have a piece of code that I am trying to get basic line from a text file, based on a user input in the screen. However that doesn't work because this only reads the first line of the text. But when I replace the variable (ban) in the for loop with a number, it works. Any help regarding this?

int ban;
int i;

scanf("%d",&ban);
for(i=ban; i<(ban+1); i++)
...
..
..

Comment: @jw23 thats not the case. I mean is it possible to identify the boundaries in a for loop, as some integer inputted by the user? is there a certain way to do it?

Comment: See carefully at your 'for' loop. It will always iterate only once, no matter 'ban' value.

Comment: @bogdan my code is actually way more complicated. However just for convenience, I did not post the whole thing. When I input the number 3 for example, is it possible to get the 3rd line in the loop with my for loop or any other method?

Comment: @user3371142 You need to move file pointer to required position. However, I don't remember any method which can move it by lines, only by bytes. See 'fseek' documentation for more details. IMHO you need to read all lines and skip not needed lines, thus your loop should start from 1 (assuming i<(ban+1)).